# Are arbitrary collections of ergodic measures "strongly mututally singular"?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I'm quite embarrassed not to know the answer to this question, but I think someone else will.

Suppose that $(X, T)$ is a topological dynamical system, and $\mathcal{E}$ is the collection of ergodic $T$-invariant Borel probability measures.

It's well-known that the measures in $\mathcal{E}$ are "pairwise mutually singular" in the sense that $\mu \perp \nu$ for all $\mu \neq \nu \in \mathcal{E}$. But must $\mathcal{E}$ be "strongly mutually singular" in the sense that there exists $f: \mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}(X)$ where $\mu(f(\mu)) = 1$, and $\nu(f(\mu)) = 0$ for all $\mu \neq \nu \in \mathcal{E}$?

This immediately holds if $\mathcal{E}$ is countable (upon taking intersections), and slightly less immediately holds for all $\mathcal{E}$ if $X$ has a countable basis (the proof of Ian Morris from ["Strongly mutually singular" families of measures, and the set of ergodic measures](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245690/) basically does this, and it also appears in the textbook of Oliveira and Viana).

But I actually don't immediately see a proof for the most general case of arbitrary $\mathcal{E}$ and $X$. My feeling is that it should hold, since it seems related to ergodic decomposition, on which I've never heard of a necessary restriction like countable basis for $X$.

Comment: If $C(X)$ is separable, say then you can take $(g_k)$ to be a dense subset and set $f(\mu)=\{x\colon \frac 1N\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}g_k(T^nx)\to\int\g\,d\mu\}$. But this is essentially repeating what Ian Morris said. What do you mean by a topological dynamical system? Are you just assuming that $X$ is compact and $T$ is continuous? or is there a Hausdorff assumption also? (in that case $C(X)$ is separable). BTW: isn't there a standard assumption that $(X,\mu)$ is a Lebesgue space for ergodic decomposition?

Comment: I won't be surprised if it is something basic like this; I'm bad at remembering these basic topology things since I always work in nice spaces. 

1. Of course I think you're right about Lebesgue; I didn't consider the fact that this implicitly restricts the $\sigma$-algebra as well! (It has a countable generating set)

2. That being said, I'm still curious if this fails in the non-Lebesgue case. I guess you need compact, Hausdorff and second countable for $C(X)$ separable, right? So maybe the question is: if $X$ is not necessarily 2nd ctable, does strong mutual singularity still hold?

Comment: Followup since I ran out of room: I guess (from Googling) that $[0, \omega_1]$ with the order topology is compact, Hausdorff, but not 2nd countable. I think $[0,1]^I$ for uncountable $I$ and the product topology is another one, but didn't check details.

Comment: Oops! I guess that's what happens if I think I remember "facts" rather than proofs.

Comment: It should not hold without a separability assumption. The ergodic decomposition needs it. Ergodic decomposition holds on Lebesgue spaces, which are spaces isomorphic to an interval together with a countable set of atoms. The proof makes use of the fact that the sigma-algebra is countably generated mod 0 in a crucial way.

Comment: Is this an answer or an intuition, i.e. do you have a counterexample for a non-Lebesgue space? I've been unable to construct one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is "no" for silly reasons. Consider
$X = \{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$
with the product topology and $T$ the identity. Then for every $x \in X$, the "delta-measure" $\delta_x$ is ergodic. I used quotes because singletons are not measurable in the product $\sigma$-algebra, but the measures can still be defined and are all distinct.

But now there are $2^c$ measures and the product $\sigma$-algebra only has (I think?) $c$ sets. So a function $f$ as in my question can't even be injective, trivially precluding strong mutual singularity.

Comment: Do you want the product $\sigma$-algebra or the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Yeah I literally just came here to post that I just realized the Borel $\sigma$-algebra for the product topology is actually not the same as the product $\sigma$-algebra here (I hate weird spaces). So I guess this is an example to show that the strong mutual singularity need not hold for an arbitrary $\sigma$-algebra, but it's not an answer to my original question. So I won't accept it :)